# Optional unidirectional one to one relationship with compound key

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, compound-key

I have 3 tables

```
-----
|foo
-----
| id pk
| rfid unique
```

```
-----
|bar
-----
|id pk
|a
|compound
|key
-----------------------------
| unique ( a, compound, key )
```

```
------------
|foo_bar_baz
------------
|id pk
|rfid
|a
|compound
|key
|baz
```

I'd like to make a `FooBarBaz` relationship entity that looks something like (written in kotlin)

```
data class FooBarBaz(
     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "rfid")
     var foo: Foo,
     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumns([ "a", "compound", "key"])
     var bar: Bar
) {
   var baz: String
}
```

and I don't want `Foo` and `Bar` to know about `FooBarBaz`, `OneToOne` seems to want a bidirectional relationship, and it wasn't happy with me adding multiple `JoinColumns`. How should I write my JPA entities?

Comment: Add explanation which columns are PK, and what relations are between tables. Would be better to paste create table script

Comment: @PeterŠály noted the primary key columns which aren't used by the foreign key (the design here is some kind of obnoxious to me, but it's... not mine). I can write out the sql if it's really needed...